# Sending GraphQL arguments to a Rest endpoint

Tags: graphql

I have an endpoint at `//myapp.com/api/graphql` and I want to send a `GraphQL` query to it that contains an argument to match.

I'm trying to send something like this:

```
https://myapp.com/api/graphql?query={assets{ownershipInfo{applicationDirector{firstName}}}}
```

That query returns a long list of assets and shows the first name of the owner. However, I want to filter the returned list so that it only returns applications that are owned by Christopher.

Something like this:

```
https://myapp.com/api/graphql?query={assets{ownershipInfo{applicationDirector{firstName (firstName: "Christopher")}}}}
```

... but this doesn't work. I don't think I have the syntax right.

Any help?

Comment: I would expect that argument should be on a different field, like `applicationDirector`... but you need to provide additional details before this question can be addressed: 1) What about this query "doesn't work" -- what error are you receiving? 2) What language/framework are you using on the client- and server-side? 3) Have you actually implemented the `firstName` argument inside your schema and resolver? If so, what does that look like?

Comment: Formatting GraphQL